# node_modules contains es6 code does not get compiled to es5 in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, babeljs, typescript-typings

I am using package which is written in ES6 but does not have a type definitions , is there a way tell the compiler to transpile the node_modules file if included in angular project???

Comment: which package contains es6 code

Comment: fusioncharts @nitin

Comment: which angular version you are using? do you have `webpack.config.js`

Comment: it is not exposed in angular latest version

Comment: using angular-cli

Comment: show your tsconfig.json

Comment: ```{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178688/discussion-between-ashok-mandal-and-nitin-pund).

Comment: @AshokMandal did you figure this out?